# JScrollBar doesn't update its maximum value after JTable changes

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a `JTable` that when clicking on the row expands it and filters all other rows in the table. When the user clicks on this expanded row again it returns to its normal size and the filter shows all the table again. All this works fine but when returning from the view of a single expanded row to the whole table I would like to set the scroll pane vertical scroll bar value to that one which is the position of the row that have been expanded. I correctly compute this value and try to set it with

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(value);
```

but as I have found with `scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum()` the scroll bar doesn't update its values after `sorter.setRowFilter(filter);` invocation. `getMaximum()` returns the height of that single row that have been expanded and for that reason scroll bar fails to set the updated value (that is typically much greater). This is the code:

```
// after this call the table shows all its rows again
sorter.setRowFilter(filter); 
System.out.println("maximum=" + scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
// shows old value when the table has consisted from a single expanded row 
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(value); // fails
```

Can anyone tell me how to let the scroll bar to know that the view of `JScrollPane` has changed so it can correctly set its maximum value? (though the scroll bar itself seems to be ok and looks like it has look properly scrolling all table). I have tried to call `revalidate` and `updateUI` methods on the `JTable` but it doesn't help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(value);
```

Try wrapping the above code in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). This will add the code to the end of the event queue.

Comment: Thank you! It has helped. But I don't understand how it works because I called the setValue method from the event dispatching thread. Why this call appeared before other pending events that have been planned earlier?

Comment: @snptc, sometimes some internal Swing methods may also call invokeLater() to add processing to be done at a later time. So it would appear that in this case this processing is overriding the value of the scrollbar. By adding your own invokeLater() you are making sure your statement is done after the internal invokeLater(). This is just something you learn from trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to revalidate the JScrollPane, but only after you invalidate the JTable. Thus, something like

```
sorter.setRowFilter(filter); 
sorter.invalidate();
// shows old value when the table has consisted from a single expanded row 
scrollPane.revalidate();
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. As @camickr have pointed I need to call invokeLater() in order to place setValue() to the end of the event queue.